# I cannot see the real time render in viewport

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I don't know why after saving my first project in blender I save that file and then when I open nextday the real time rendering is stop working in my viewport. I search many saying try clrt+alt+b I try but nothing happened.

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: When you re-open blender you are in solid mode by default. Press Z in the 3D viewport and select either "Material Preview" or "Rendered" from the pie menu.

Comment: @Chris We should be encouraging new users to explain their questions thoroughly  in text/screenshots before reaching for blend files as a last resort.  See [this meta post](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2793/5705).

Comment: there may be a pause button in the top right corner

Comment: Sorry it my foolish mistake. I am new in blender. Later I found that when we open blender it by default in solid mode. If we need real time rendering then we need to switch to rendered mode that what I forgot to do.